# How do I change the text of the MDLabel when MDFlatButton is pressed

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm currently having difficulty trying to get my MDFlatButton to change the text of my MDLabel when on_press. The current error that I get is regarding ids but I can't see what the problem is with it. Hopefully someone can help because this I've been struggling for the last hour with this and can't figure it out here's my code. I have tried to do it with instances like in java but don't think that is the way to do it.

main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.uix.relativelayout import MDRelativeLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class HomeScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class UpscaleScreen(MDScreen):
    def change_text(self):
        self.ids["select"].text = "Changed"
        return


class ColouriseScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(MDScreenManager):
    pass



class ContentNavigationDrawer(MDRelativeLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return kv

    us = UpscaleScreen()
    us.change_text()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<DrawerClickableItem@MDNavigationDrawerItem>
    focus_color: "#e7e4c0"
    text_color: "#4a4939"
    icon_color: "#4a4939"
    ripple_color: "#c5bdd2"
    selected_color: "#0c6c4d"


<DrawerLabelItem@MDNavigationDrawerItem>
    text_color: "#4a4939"
    icon_color: "#4a4939"
    focus_behavior: False
    selected_color: "#4a4939"
    _no_ripple_effect: True

<ContentNavigationDrawer>

    MDNavigationDrawerMenu:

        MDNavigationDrawerHeader:
            title: "PyUpscaler"
            title_color: "#4a4939"
            text: "Let's upscale!"
            spacing: "4dp"
            padding: "12dp", 0, 0, "56dp"

        DrawerClickableItem:
            icon: "arrow-top-right-bottom-left"
            text_right_color: "#4a4939"
            text: "Upscale"
            on_release:
                root.screen_manager.current = "upscale"
                root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

        DrawerClickableItem:
            icon: "palette"
            text: "Colourise"


MDScreen:

    MDTopAppBar:
        id: toolbar
        title: "Navigation Drawer"
        elevation: 4
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        md_bg_color: "#e7e4c0"
        specific_text_color: "#4a4939"
        left_action_items:
            [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    MDNavigationLayout:

    MDScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager

        MDScreen:
            name: "home"

        UpscaleScreen:
            name: "upscale"

            MDBoxLayout:
                size_hint: [.9, .9]
                pos_hint: { 'top' : .95, 'right': .95}

                MDLabel:
                    id: select
                    text: "Please Choose a file..."

                MDFlatButton:
                    text: "Press Me!"
                    on_press: app.us()

        MDScreen:
            name: "colourise"

    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer

        ContentNavigationDrawer:
            screen_manager: screen_manager
            nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

Comment: The `select` id is defined within the root (MDScreen) of your `kv`. It will not appear as an `id` of the `UpscaleScreen`.